# convert binary array to int16

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

the array is a waveform. I can easily convert a binary array to `int8`, when each byte is 1 sample. when working with 12bit, I can set the instrument to send 2bytes (word mode) for each sample. I have been looking on the web to convert the 2bytes/sample binary array into a `int16` vector, but have not been able so far.
this works with 1 byte per sample

```
data = numpy.fromstring(dataword, dtype=numpy.int8)
```

same using unpack

```
data = numpy.array(unpack('%sb' %len(dataword) ,dataword))
```

can't figure out how to make it work with 2bytes/sample.
thanks

Comment: Where did `dataword` come from? How you created it?

Comment: Did you not just try changing that `8` to a `16`? `np.fromstring(dataword, dtype=np.int16)` works for me

Comment: Also, shouldn't you use `h` (signed short) with `struct.unpack`?

Comment: yes I tried...but the plot is completely wrong...but need to check one more thing..will soon get back

Comment: YES.. working... Eric, you made me think that I was not converting the vertical scale correctly, that part of the code was still for 8 bit and not for 16 bit vertical scale... going to tray the %sh in unpack now.

Comment: the command data = numpy.array(unpack('%sh' %len(dataword) ,dataword)) returns an error: unpack requires a string argument of length 160000. Dataword length is 40000 bytes, or 20K samples. can some explain how to use the '%sh' part of unpack?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `unpack` at all, when I just gave you the other solution?

Comment: @Eric. your solution is to my opinion more elegant, but it was bothering me not being able to make the other one work as well... just an typical engineer attitude... not working, so need to figure out why. Both working, so I am happy now!

Comment: @MaurizioMastrofini: `struct.unpack` is likely to be way slower

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `struct.unpack` like this:

```
data = numpy.array(unpack('%sb' %len(dataword) ,dataword))
```

You should use it like this:

```
data = numpy.array(unpack('%sh' % len(dataword) / struct.calcsize('h'), dataword))
#----------------------------^ notice the 'h', signed short, 16 bits
```

You must divide `len(dataword)` by the numeric size you are reading, in this case two bytes. It is good practice to use `calcsize` for that, but if you already know, simply divide by two.

Comment: yes it is working just parenthesis are needed to avoid syntax error:               data = numpy.array(unpack('%sh' %(len(dataword) / 2) ,dataword))     thanks, this is working well

Comment: Nice! If this answer solved the problem, you can accept the answer! :D :D :D I'm glad to have helped!